# Copy matching information from specified range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I like this block of code, it works but to an extent. I want to search an item number in a certain cell on a certain sheet. From there I want to copy all cells related to the item number. The code below copies every single item, it does not search the specific item number. How can I get it to search an item number first and then copy those rows/columns associated with that item number with a single add button (which I have already created)?

```
function moveValuesOnly(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('DISHES');
  var source = ss.getRange ("DISHES!B:F");
  var resultss = ss.getSheetByName("Order Guide");
  // destination tab
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
  source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
  source.clear ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use query? Assuming the item number is in  sheet DISHES B:F, on sheet Order Guide enter this query in Order Guide cell A2. Enter the item to search for in Order Guide A1. It will return data for all rows of that item.

```
=query(DISHES!B:F,"select * where B contains '" & A1 & "'")
```

Comment: It doesn't work the way I want it to, plus it takes long to load. I just wanted something that can copy and paste from sheet to another.